# Lenovo G50-80 Ubuntu 14.04 Wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo, iwlwifi

Good afternoon.

I've bought a Lenovo G50-80, and I've installed Ubuntu 14. I have a problem with Wifi, because it only works for few minutes, when in Windows 8 it works fine. I've read several threads about it, but I have not been able to solve it. I've reinstalled Ubuntu 14, but the problem persists.

EDIT. Output of the command: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot.

This will disable 802.11n mode, that works badly with many Intel wireless adapters.

If this does not help, you can try this command

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0 bt_coex_active=0"
```

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 . Sometimes my wifi doesn't work with your solution, and I don't know why... Do you need more information about my wireless adapter? Sorry and thanks for your time!

Comment: @Alejandro I updated the answer.

Comment: ok thanks! I'm going to try with the new command and I will report you with the results!

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 . The problem has appeared again with the last solution that you gave me, and my wifi doesn't work each five minutes. I don't know if you have more tricks in order to solve it. I'm really desperate... Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Can anybody help me please? I'm really desperate with this situation and I don't know what can I do...

Comment: What is the kernel version? `uname -r`?

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 , the kernel version is 3.19.0-31-generic