# Ubuntu 17.10.1 Network problems

Tags: networking

Super newbie here. I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop. Can someone tell me how can i setup a network connection? Thanks.

The results from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` are:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [1434:465] (rev1)
Subsytem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advcanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
  Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev ff)
```

Comment: Searching for "Lenovo G50-80 ubuntu wifi" found a few possible similar Q's on this site, try their answers and then reply saying which one worked (if any): https://askubuntu.com/questions/681828/lenovo-g50-80-ubuntu-14-04-wifi-not-working [the next answer requires an internet connection to install a package, or a usb to d/l and install manually] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007669/wifi-doesnt-work-on-my-lenovo-g50-80ubuntu-17-10-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wired connection problems

Your ISP must have things set up so you have to go through the router to get an internet connection, so leave the router connected to the main "incoming" wire and use another wire from one of the router's lan ports to your laptop.

Now that you've got a network connection, you can try using a package manager (like Ubuntu's Software Center, or Synaptic, or plain `apt` / `apt-get`) and try to fix:

## Wireless connection problems

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. reboot (I hate rebooting linux, there might be a combination of `rmmod` and `modprobe` or restarting services that could avoid a reboot, but I don't know it)

Adding a few lines like
`blacklist b43`
`blacklist bcma`
`blacklist ssb`
to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` may or may not be required, try without first  see the first link below for more info.

If it works, then you should see the desktop's GUI wifi icon in the panel / menu bar and see & connect to wireless networks, similar to this:

[image: Wifi icon menu]

More info:

- [Is it possible to use Broadcom BCM43142 wifi in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765584/is-it-possible-to-use-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-in-ubuntu-16-04%22)
- [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Finaly solved it with the help of this link your provided: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers.  After is install the driver i had to turn off  SECURE BOOT(It was already turned off but after i toggled problem was solved :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Towards the top right side of your screen, there should be a weird cog looking thing, the time, a speaker icon, battery, and last should be two arrows pointing up and down in opposite directions. Click on the arrows and it should give you an option of network connection options.

If this does not work, try navigation to the top left and left click `Activities`. In the search bar, type in `Network` and select `Network`. There should be more options for networks and connection types.

Comment: I only have the speaker, battery and a submenu arrow thing with some other info(sound, luminosity, vpn. battery power settings, account settings)

Comment: @AlexDani Alright, then try going to the top left corner and click on `Activities`. Then type in Network. Click on Network and it should give you more network connection options.

Comment: The network panel shows Wired(which is unplugged right now), Vpn not set up, network proxy automatic. I connected the laptop to the ethernet cable and wired showed me a connection but still i was unable to access mozzila pages(Server not found). Also Wi-Fi panel shows(No wi-fi adapter found). I looked up the forum and someone suggested sudo apt-get update  but i get errors with dns server and fails to fetch.

Comment: @AlexDani lol, yeah. apt-get requires an internet connection so that won't help at the moment. Try restarting network manager by opening a terminal. Go back to activities and search for terminal. Once opened, type `sudo service network-manager restart`. It will ask for your password but it should restart your network manager and give it a kick in the pants. After doing that, try connecting with Ethernet again and running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure to get new updates that could help. If that doesn't work then let me know, there are other options

Comment: I typed `sudo service network-manager restart` introduced password then nothing showed in terminal(guessed it worked? I don't know). Plugged the ethernet cable and still when i type `sudo apt-get update` 4 errors return(DNS problems with archive.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Using an ethernet cable should definitely have worked, does your router work with the same wire with other devices? And search the web for your laptop model with wireless or wifi, you might need to do something special to get it recognized

Comment: @Xen2050 I have 1 ethernet cable plugged in router. When i plug the cable in laptop i get an wired connection, but when i access a firefox page i get "Server not found". Model of laptop is Lenovo G50-80. I have not found anything that I understand and might solve my problem.

Comment: @AlexDani Alright, here is a link with a similar problem and a few different things to try https://askubuntu.com/questions/488139/installed-ubuntu-14-04-cannot-connect-to-internet-with-wired-or-wireless-conne

Comment: It's either wifi-menu, wpa-supplicant, or wicd-curses, but more than likely it's wpa. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant   nmcli and conman are usually installed by the user after the install

Comment: You may also want to put your wireless interface up with ip link set wlan0 up; ifconfig

Comment: You mean you're unplugging the main "internet" cable from your router, and plugging it into your laptop? Does that work to connect any other laptops? Your ISP might have things set up so you have to go through the router to get an internet connection, try leaving the router connected and use another wire from one of the router's lan ports to your laptop.

Comment: @Xen2050 Wow i feel so dumb. Yep i connected the cable from router's lan ports to laptop and now i have internet connection. Still wifi adapter is not found. Any more ideas on that? Also thanks all for the answers.

Comment: Some ISP's are weird, don't want you using your own router or something. At least now you can try installing things... I might as well post my comments as an answer, got 1/2 the problem solved at least

Comment: Maybe you should try the cinnamon flavor lol its more like windows